# How to pass variables from Jenkinsfile to shell command

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I want to use a variable which I am using inside of my `Jenkinsfile` script, and then pass its value into a shell script execution (either as an environment variable or command line parameter).

But the following `Jenkinsfile`:

```
for (i in [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]) {
    echo i
    sh 'echo "from shell i=$i"'
}
```

Gives the output:

```
a
from shell i=
b
from shell i=
c
from shell i=
```

Desired output is something like:

```
a
from shell i=a
b
from shell i=b
c
from shell i=c
```

Any idea how to pass the value of `i` to the shell scipt?

**Edit:** Based upon [Matt's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41550146/2880699) answer, I now use this solution:

```
for (i in [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]) {
    echo i
    sh "i=${i}; " + 'echo "from shell i=$i"'
}
```

The advantage is, that I don't need to escape the `"` in the shell script.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Your code is using a literal string and therefore your Jenkins variable will not be interpolated inside the shell command. You need to use `"` to interpolate your variable inside your strings inside the `sh`. `'` will just pass a literal string. So we need to make a few changes here.

The first is to change the `'` to `"`:

```
for (i in [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]) {
  echo i
  sh "echo "from shell i=$i""
}
```

However, now we need to escape the `"` on the inside:

```
for (i in [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]) {
  echo i
  sh "echo \"from shell i=$i\""
}
```

Additionally, if a variable is being appended directly to a string like you are doing above (`$i` onto `i=`), we need to close it off with some curly braces:

```
for (i in [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]) {
  echo i
  sh "echo \"from shell i=${i}\""
}
```

That will get you the behavior you desire.

Comment: THANK YOU! I wish I could upvote this 1000 times! The single quote vs. double quotes was my issue!

Answer (score 28):

Extension to Matts answer:
For multi-line sh scripts use

```
sh """
  echo ${paramName}
"""
```

instead of

```
sh '''
  echo ${paramName}
'''
```

Comment: post {
        always {
            script {
                def body
                    sh(
                        script: '''
                                cat "/tmp/output.text"
                                body=$(</tmp/output.text)
                                echo "$body"
                                pwd
                                
                        '''
                    )
                
                if (currentBuild.result == 'SUCCESS') {
                    sendEmail("Successfully", "Sending Body ${body}", 'a@b.c', ' ')

Comment: I am getting in email Sending Body null..... this means variable from sh scope is not outside it so how can I make this work ?

Comment: Most probably the problem is in non escaped $ which is being resolved by groovy before value is given to script/shell. Try using body=\$(</tmp/output.text) so that $ is provided for resolution to shell.

Comment: or alternatively use ' or ''' instead of "/""". Then the string will be given to shell as is without trying to resolve any values inside.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
for (i in [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]) {
    echo i
    sh '''
    echo "from shell i=$i"
    '''
}
```

Comment: i cant check, but also try to surround the var like this ${i}

Comment: Both won't work. Checking groovy syntax, the difference between `'` and `'''` is just single line string versus multiline string.

Comment: I believe `sh """` would work. i.e. triple double-quotes instead of triple single-quotes

Answer (score 0):

For multi-line, this should also work:

```
for (i in [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]) {
    echo i
    sh '''
        VAR1="'''+i+'''"
        echo $VAR1
    '''
}
```