# Jenkinsfile - write environment variable to a file

Tags: jenkins

In my Jenkinsfile, I'm trying to add a environment variable to a file, however not able to do so - seems like some small syntax thing, however I've tried so many different variations.

So the parameter I want is `"${params.Spec}"`, currently used like:

```
environment {
        SPECTORUN = "${params.Spec}"
}
```

Then in my `script` block i'm trying:

`sh "echo Run:\"${params.Spec}\" >> allure-results/environment.properties"`

Any help would be appreciated.

FOUND THE ANSWER HERE:
[How to pass variables from Jenkinsfile to shell command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41539076/how-to-pass-variables-from-jenkinsfile-to-shell-command)

Comment: What do you get with this ```sh "echo Run:\"${params.Spec}\"```?

Comment: @Tuan Nothing - I think i see the issue i',m passing a Jenkins variabel into the shell - how will shell know whats outside. Need to figure out how to pass that varibale into shell

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28572080/how-to-access-parameters-in-a-parameterized-build