# Mix and match shell variables with groovy variables in Jenkinsfile

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I've tried various variations of the below code, none of them seems to work

```
def runScript(command){
    sh '''#!/bin/bash
        file="env.txt"
        while IFS='=' read -r key value
        do
            export ${key}="${value}"
        done < "$file"
        pwd
        "${command}"
    '''
}
```

`command` is the dynamic shell command that I want to execute after re-creating the environment variables from `env.txt`

Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this

```
   def runScript(command){
        sh '''#!/bin/bash
            file="env.txt"
            while IFS='=' read -r key value
            do
                export ${key}="${value}"
            done < "$file"
            pwd
        ''' + "${command}"
    }
```

The single quotes `'''` will create multi-line shell script. The `"` quotes will get the value of command variable and concatenate it with shell script.
Note that there are two shell variables `key` & `value` & hence, `'''` can't be replaced with `"""`

References :

[Access a Groovy variable from within shell step in Jenkins pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39982414/access-a-groovy-variable-from-within-shell-step-in-jenkins-pipeline)

[How to pass variables from Jenkinsfile to shell command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41539076/how-to-pass-variables-from-jenkinsfile-to-shell-command)

Comment: You could also just replace ‘’’ by “””

Comment: @JoergS that won't work because it'll try to replace `key` & `value` variables as well, which is incorrect.