# Jenkins Declarative Pipeline is not supporting shell/bash syntax

Tags: bash, variables, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a shell script inside my jenkins pipeline which will call mvn. For that i have to pass variable value to mvn. The variable is not passing inside the Jenkins pipeline's shell. But when trying from local machine shell it is working fine as expected.

ARTIFACT_NAME="Sample_Artifact"

```
pipeline{
    agent {
        node{
            label "${AGENT}"
    
    }
    }
   stages{
         
        
        stage("Setting MultiJob Properties"){
            steps{
                      sh '''set +x



export VERSION=$(mvn -B -q -Dexec.executable=echo -Dexec.args=\${${ARTIFACT_NAME}} )

echo $VERSION
'''

            }
        }
   }
}
```

Expected Process: export VERSION=$(mvn -B -q -Dexec.executable=echo -Dexec.args=${Sample_Artifact} )

Expected Output: 1.0001

`ARTIFACT_NAME` - I am passing it from Jenkins UI.

`${${ARTIFACT_NAME}}` - This variable is perfectly replace value in Freestyle jobs and it is throwing error in the Pipeline jobs.

Error Message: script.sh: 3: Bad substitution

Can Anyone please help me to resolve the issue?

Comment: What kind of error? Closing `}` is missing by `${${ARTIFACT_NAME}`

Comment: Show your actual pipeline. Probably needs " instead of  '. [Explanation,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53402569/598141)

Comment: FYR,


pipeline{
    agent {
        node{
            label "${AGENT}"
    
    }
    }
   stages{
         
        
        stage("Setting MultiJob Properties"){
            steps{
                      sh '''set +x



export VERSION=$(mvn -B -q -Dexec.executable=echo -Dexec.args=\${${ARTIFACT_NAME}} )

echo $VERSION
'''

            }
        }
   }
}

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: For Example:

The following code running without any errors in my local machine shell but when i was trying from Jenkins pipeline it is throwing error.

#!/bin/sh
ARTIFACT_NAME="test"
sample=$(echo \${${ARTIFACT_NAME}})
echo "$sample"

shell output: ${test}

Jenkins pipeline Error: script.sh: 3: Bad substitution @Melkjot

Answer (score 0):

As Ian wrote, you're passing the whole script as a literal (''') instead of an interpolated string ("""), so the variable name doesn't get substituted with its value:

```
pipeline{
  agent {
    node {
      label AGENT
    }
  }
  stages {
    stage("Setting MultiJob Properties") {
      steps {
        sh """set +x
           export VERSION=\$(mvn -B -q -Dexec.executable=echo -Dexec.args=\${$ARTIFACT_NAME})
           echo \$VERSION"""
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am getting syntax error if i replace with " instead of '

Error msg: Illegal string body

Comment: the solution is not working @towel

Comment: This is how you use variables in scripts. I missed the escaping of the dollar sign in $VERSION - added it now.

Comment: Actually the test case should pass the output like this,

If the ARTIFACT_NAME="Sample_Art"

it should pass the expression to mvn like below,

$(mvn -B -q -Dexec.executable=echo -Dexec.args=${"Sample_Art"})

@towel

Comment: You're basically describing what I did :) Also you don't need to quote the variable name. Have you tried running the fixed version of the solution?

Comment: yeah i tried and it is not working @towel

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I tested this code on my Jenkins instance and it worked. What error do you get?